Implement text formatting in my android note app
So the feature I want is that I want to select the text and should be able to bold it or make it italic etc.
I am using following code to achieve that:
 var annotatedString = remember { mutableStateOf(AnnotatedString("")) }

    var textFieldValue =
        remember { mutableStateOf<TextFieldValue>(TextFieldValue(annotatedString.value)) }

fun makeTextBold(textFieldValue: MutableState<TextFieldValue>) {
    val selection = textFieldValue.value.selection
    if (!selection.collapsed) {
        val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            append(textFieldValue.value.annotatedString.subSequence(0, selection.start))
            
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)) {
                append(
                    textFieldValue.value.annotatedString.subSequence(
                        selection.start,
                        selection.end
                    )
                )
            }

            append(
                textFieldValue.value.annotatedString.subSequence(
                    selection.end,
                    textFieldValue.value.annotatedString.length
                )
            )
            

        }

        textFieldValue.value = textFieldValue.value.copy(annotatedString)
    }
}

Then I use my textFieldValue in TextField

   TextField(
        value = textFieldValue.value,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue.value = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
    )


The problem with this code is it only makes it bold when the text is selected, when I deselect the text , text becomes normal again (not bold). What am I doing wrong ?

Similar to this

This is a known bug reported on the Google Issue Tracker. Please upvote it and leave a comment there to draw more attention to it.
The problem is that the applied SpanStyles are not present in the TextFieldValue that is supplied in the onValueChange callback. So whenever the onValueChange callback is invoked, you will overwrite your current annotatedString with an annotatedString without any SpanStyles.

Besides that, your annotatedString variable is actually redundant:
val textFieldValue = remember { 
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(AnnotatedString(""))) 
}

